# Tensorboard error: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

My goal: Add arbitrary text to tensorboard.

My code:

```
text = "muh teeeext"
summary = tf.summary.text("Muh taaaag", tf.convert_to_tensor(text))
writer.add_summary(summary)
```

My error:

```
  File xxx, line xxx, in xxx
    writer.add_summary(summary)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py", line 123, in add_summary
    for value in summary.value:
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, this has something to do with a tensorboard update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`writer.add_summary(summary)` is a tensor. the tensorboard writer expects a string for the summary. To get the summary from the tensor, add an `eval()` to the `add_summary` line like so:

`writer.add_summary(summary).eval()`